# How to find paramter C (horizontal shift of cosine function) from this graph?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

[image]

I need to reconstruct the function from this graph.

Long story short, I got this far: $y=\pm2\cos(\frac{4}{7}(x+C))+4$

Once I will know $C$ I will be able to figure out the sign of the leading coefficient.
So I want to know just two things:

1)What is the exact value of $C$?

2)How to deduce said value?

Comment: Where is the curve maximal / minimal / at is average value?  Where is the cosine function at these values?

Comment: Normally, cosine reaches it maximum value at x= 0.  Here it is at x= $\pi$.  So you want $(4/7)(\pi+ C)= 0$ so $C= -\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shifted up the cosine graph by $4$, stretch it vertically by a factor of $2$, shrink it horizontally by $\frac47$ and observe that the peak is now $(\pi, 6)$.  That is we have shifted to the right by $\pi$.

Hence $$y = 2\cos \left(\frac47 (x-\pi) \right) + 4$$

---

Edit:

- Suppose $y=2\cos \left( \frac47 \left( x+C \right)\right)+4$.

Let $6=2\cos \left( \frac47 \left( \pi+C \right)\right)+4$  where $6$ is the maximum value, then we would let to set the argument of cosine to be $0$. Hence we can pick $C$ is $-\pi$.

- Suppose $y=-2\cos \left( \frac47 \left( x+C \right)\right)+4$.

Let $2=-2\cos \left( \frac47 \left( -\frac{3\pi}4+C \right)\right)+4$  where $2$ is the minimum value, then we would let to set the argument of cosine to be $0$. Hence we can pick $C$ to be $\frac{3\pi}4$.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why shift must be equal to pi. Also unclear how you resolved plus/minus ambiguity

Comment: look at the shape of the cosine curve and compare with what you achieve. We shifted the maximum to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find C. We don't know sign yet, but we know that if x=π, then ±2cos((4/7)(π+C))+4=6.

±2cos((4/7)(π+C))+4=6 (-4 from both sides and then divide both by 2)

±cos((4/7)(π+C))=1

From this we can conclude that either we have two minuses canceling each other or two pluses, as cos((4/7)(π+C)) can either give -1 or 1 here. Let's see both paths.

1)(when -)

-cos((4/7)(π+C))=1 (we multiply both sides by -1)

cos((4/7)(π+C))=-1

Then let's make replacement (4/7)(π+С)=y

cos(y)=-1

Remember unit circle. It will be true for y=pi+2πk, where k∊Z (i.e. k is an integer). We want the smallest absolute value of y, thus we take k=0, thus we we get y=π Thus we have (4/7)(π+С)=π and if we solve for C we will get C=3π/4 Thus we get **y=-2cos((4/7)(x+(3π/4)))+4**

2)(when +)

cos((4/7)(π+C))=1

Then let's make replacement (4/7)(π+С)=y

Remember unit circle. It will be true for y=0+2πk, where k∊Z (i.e. k is an integer). We want the smallest absolute value of y, thus we take k=0, thus we we get y=0. Thus we have (4/7)(π+С)=0 and if we solve for C we will get C=-π. Thus we get **y=2cos((4/7)(x-π))+4**

Both signs lead to valid results, but + leads to the most elegant one.